# Preserve access privileges when using '->' operator

Tags: c++

I have two classes,

```cpp
template<class Type>
class SafePtr {
public:
    SafePtr() {}
    ~SafePtr() {}

    void Lock(Type* data, void* key)
    {
        if (!pKey)
        {
            pKey = key;
            pData = data;
        }
    }

    Type* Unlock(void* key) const
    {
        if (key == pKey)
            return pData;
    }

    Type* operator->() 
    {
        return pData;
    }

private:
    Type* pData = nullptr;
    void* pKey = nullptr;
};

template<class Type>
class SafePtrArray {
public:
    SafePtrArray() {}
    ~SafePtrArray() {}

    template<class... Args>
    SafePtr<Type> CreatePtr(Args&&... args)
    {
        Type* data = new Type(args...);
        ptrs.insert(ptrs.end(), data);

        SafePtr<Type> ptr;
        ptr.Lock(data, this);
        return ptr;
    }

    Type* UnlockPtr(const SafePtr<int>& ptr)
    {
        return ptr.Unlock(this);
    }

    void Destroy(const SafePtr<int>& ptr)
    {
        Type* pointer = ptr.Unlock(this);

        for (auto itr = ptrs.begin(); itr != ptrs.end(); itr++)
        {
            if ((*itr) == pointer)
            {
                delete pointer;
                ptrs.erase(itr);
            }
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<Type*> ptrs;
};
```

The goal is to protect a pointer so that the user can access its members but not get to manipulate its actual pointer (mainly delete it prematurely). And also I need to store all the pointers in an array so that when the parent object destroys, I can automatically destroy all the allocated pointers

For this I use two classes, `SafePtr` and `SafePtrArray`. `SafePtrArray` creates and stores the pointers and wraps them in the `SafePtr` and returns it to the user. `SafePtr` is just a wrapper and **should not** let the user get access to the underlying pointer but will allow them to access its members.

It works fine at first but soon I found this error,

```cpp
int main()
{
    SafePtrArray<int> ptr;
    auto pInt = ptr.CreatePtr();
    int* i = pInt.operator->();     // Users can get access to the underlying pointer using this.

    ptr.Destroy(pInt);
}
```

Is there a way to prevent users from getting access to the underlying type and prevent them from manipulating the pointer while having the privilege to access its members?

Comment: Why not just use good old `shared_ptr` and its friends, leaving your users with familiar interface?

Comment: Can't you make the operator private?

Comment: Sounds like you are describing the [Pointer to Implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) pattern (also known as the PImpl pattern).  But `SafePtr` isn't that pattern.  I don't think in C++ one could make a generic template that would do all the PImpl forwarding for you (but I may be wrong, those template developers do amazing things).

Comment: @MichałKaczorowski But still the user can potentially delete the pointer right?..

Comment: @rturrado Then how can we access the pointer's members and values?

Comment: You can't do that in a generic way. What is the reason why you need that? For any type in the stdlib and other libraries, users generally have access to objects (and their pointers) which they must not delete because they don't have ownership for those objects? (for `std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr` you could call `get()`, for `std::vector()` you can call `data()`, for `std::list` you can retrieve the pointer for the elements, …)

Comment: @Eljay I'm sorry but no, its not what I'm describing. I don't think you quite grasped the question. My question is, how to let users access the pointer's data and not let them delete the actual pointer.

Comment: @t.niese Yes, that's why I tried implementing it myself ;)

Comment: @D-RAJ well the user could still do `SafePtrArray<int> ptr; delete &ptr;` - which of course is undefined behavior - but deleting an object you don't own will normal also result in undefined behavior (due to double free or access of the already deleted object). It sounds like you either want to ensure that a user not knowing the language does not do anything wrong or to get around a possible design flaw in your code or the documentation.

Comment: I don't have the ability to *prove* that this is not possible, but I've seen good people try and it seems to be not possible.  If you really need to hide your pointers from hostile programmers, your best solution is probably to invent an API that doesn't offer the users anything that acts like a pointer.

Comment: Given `operator->` defnitionally provides access to the pointer, I think your solution is to stop thinking *any* reasonable user would get at the pointer that way when it's clearly not theirs to play with, and write off any user who would do that as morons. Even if you managed some terrible hack to enable the behavior you want, it's still C++; they have direct memory access, they can do terrible non-standard things to access that pointer if they want; *your job is to make it hard to do the wrong thing by accident, it's impossible to make it impossible for a motivated user to misuse your API.*

Comment: The typical C++ approach is to document ownership of the pointer, declare that any attempts to delete my pointer will result in undefined behavior, and just let a determined programmer shoot oneself in the foot. C++ is not a safe language. If you adopt this mindset, `std::shared_ptr` appears to do what you want -- note how it lacks a `release()` method, unlike a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @D-RAJ _"But still the user can potentially delete the pointer right?"_ If they do, that's their problem. Don't waste your time on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still think you try to solve a problem that has more to do with possible flaws in the design of the API/of the code, the documentation, or with the lack of C++ knowledge of the one using it, with a "solution" that has more cons than pros.

If a C++ programmer does not know what ownership is or does not respect it and blindly deletes objects or frees the memory of pointers, then there will be much bigger concerns. You likely will move the problem just to a different part of the code.

Having that said, the closest you can do to not expose the pointer right now is something like this:

(The code is just a proof of concept, so things like `call` might need to be improved)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Test {
  void foo(int x, int y, std::string str) {
    std::cout << x << " " << y << " " << str << std::endl;
  }

  double test = 0.5;
};

template <typename T>
struct Ptr {

  template <auto M, typename... Args>
  auto call(Args... args) {
    return (obj.*M)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

  template <auto M>
  auto get() { 
    return (obj.*M);
  }

protected:
  T obj;
};

int main() {
  Ptr<Test> p;

  p.call<&Test::foo>(1, 2, "hello");
  std::cout << p.get<&Test::test>() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

But I still don't think that this is a good approach.

And a user can still mess around with the code and do something bad like:

```
int main() {
  Ptr<Test> p;
  
  delete &p;

  return 0;
}
```

Or this, which for sure is undefined behavior, but that does not really matter as deleting a not owned object will also result in undefined behavior at some point:

```
template<typename T>
struct Ptr {
protected:
    T *obj;
}

template<typename T>
struct Ptr2 {
public:
    T *obj;
};

int main()
{
    Ptr<Test> p;
    Ptr2<Test> *p2 = reinterpret_cast<Ptr2<Test>*>(&p);
    
    std::cout << p2->obj << std::endl;
}
```

So there is no protection again such things.

Besides the shown code, there is a proposal for [reflection](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0578r1.html) that is feature complete now, which would allow getting information about the members of a type, but this was not added to c++20, and one for [metaclasses](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0707r3.pdf) which is also not in the standard yet.

With these two proposals, you might be able to implement something better useable. But my concerns about the benefits of this remain.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to prevent users from getting access to the underlying type and prevent them from manipulating the pointer while having the privilege to access its members?

Under certain conditions, no, this is not possible. If the underlying `Type` is a [standard layout class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout) then providing access to the first non-static non-bitfield data member breaks your goal. *(Caveat: providing access to just the **value** of the member is a different story.)* The address of that member can be converted to a pointer to the underlying object via [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), which allows calling `delete` on that pointer. (Well, "allows" in the sense that the call is syntactically valid. Not much else matters for "allows" since we are headed into undefined behavior anyway.)

For classes that are not standard layout, there are probably compiler-specific (non-portable) methods to achieve the same effect (converting the address of a data member into a pointer to the underlying object). There is no reason for a compiler to try actively to thwart such things.

If a programmer is determined to invoke undefined behavior, there is little you can do to stop it.